# How can I curve fit an oscillating plot without knowing the underlying function?

Tags: curve-fitting

How i can curve fit an oscillating plot without knowing its function in python?
the objective is to curve fit the plot and then try to know the equation of the curve fit.
here is my plot image.

I tried polynomial fit
gaussian fit with multiplied sinc function
nothing work
[image]

Comment: You could try learning something about the underlying function via frequency analysis (FFT, Fast Fourier Transformation); e.g., you might find the lowest considerable frequency that occurs in the signal / data; if the signal oscillates, then probably with that frequency. May or may not work in your case.

Comment: The objective is to use parametric function instead of Fourier series